# How to fix: Uncaught Error: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux

When I compile and run my Webpack application, I keep getting thrown this error. Anyone have an idea what my be causing it. I have tried adding the `<div id="root"></div>` before the script tag but that didnt solve it. I am using webpack version 3.3.0.
Thanks. This is my webpack.config file.

```
 var webpack = require('webpack');
 var path = require('path');
 var react = require('react');
 var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

 var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'public');
 var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/app');

 var config = {
  entry: APP_DIR + '/index.js',
  output: {
   path: BUILD_DIR,
   filename: 'bundle.js'
   },
  module: {
     rules: [{
       test: /\.js?$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    exclude: [/node_modules/],
    use: [{
        loader: "babel-loader",
        options: {
                    presets: ["stage-0","es2015","react"],
                    plugins: ["transform-class-properties", "react-html-attrs"]
                }

    }]  
},
{
 test: /\.css?$/,
 use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
 },
 {
   test: /\.html?$/,
  use: [
    "htmllint-loader",
   {
     loader: "html-loader",
         options: {}
   }
   ]
  }],

 },
  devServer: {
  contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
  compress: true,
  port: 9000
 },
 plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          title: 'My Project',
        filename: 'main.html'
    })]
}

 module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add index.js file in src/client/app/ and make sure you have import ReactDom from 'react-dom;

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class App extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
     <div>
       <h1>Hello App</h1>
     </div>
    )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementByID('root'));
```